# integrate html, css code into a drupal theme

Tags: theming

My client has hired a vendor to create html, css, javascript for a website and we are planning to use Drupal as CMS for this website. I'm one of the front end devs involved in choosing a base theme for this site and our team is fairly new to Drupal. How do we integrate this vendor provided html,css code into a drupal theme? What are the things we need to know before integrating the code? How do we start with integrating this code into Drupal? How do we select a theme that would work with the vendor provided code? What are the things we need to look for ?

Comment: If you're new to Drupal and you must create a theme for your vendor, then you should read about theming. See https://drupal.org/documentation/theme. Asking "how to do look and feel" becomes asking "how to theme" in Drupal, and it is like asking how to do an SQL SELECT statement: before asking about here you should read about the core knowledge first, to avoid too-broad questions

Answer (score 1):

Read about [theming](http://drupal.org/documentation/theme) to create your own theme. If what you need is just to append files and folders to your drupal theme without altering it, you must create your own module for your application functions (if you have any), and add your script or styles files with calls to:

```
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'yourmodulefolder').'/path/to/your/js/file')
drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'yourmodulefolder').'/path/to/your/css/file')
```

See [Adding CSS files](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/7) and [Adding JS files](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) here for more information. The use cases I gave you are for files (assuming the files are inside your module).

You can add these calls in any hook in your module (I take the dirty way: I put this kind of lines in the global scope, althought it's not the better solution, it doesn't break what I'm doing).